# Cannot Open Display Error- While trying to Open Thunar (Google Cloud)

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, google-compute-engine

I am using Cent OS 7 in Gcloud. I just installed Thunar using this command

`yum install Thunar`

Then run this command
`thunar` to open up Thunar File manager. But it says:-

```
Thunar: Cannot Open Display:
```

I got this error too while trying to use Nemo and Nautilus. But could not solve it. Please help me to get through this...

Comment: You're trying to use GUI application via SSH connection? Probably console file manager like Midnight Commander https://midnight-commander.org/ is more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Yes, but Midnight Commander does not fullfill my need. I already have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to run X application using a remote SSH connection you need:

1. A local X server (XQuartz for instance)
2. X-Forwarding SSH connection ( ssh -X for instance )
3. exported DISPLAY environment variable.

There is more to it but although I didn't read that reference, it seems to be precisely what you need:
https://kb.iu.edu/d/bdnt

This is slower than using a local file manager, but it could suits you.
As an alternative, using VNC or other remote-desktop type client could be a solution as well.